# Genus of compact Riemann surface $\{[x_0,x_1,x_2]\in\Bbb P^2\mid x_2^2x_0=\prod_{i=1}^3(x_1-\lambda_ix_0),\lambda_i\in\Bbb C\}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

**My question:**

Compute genus of compact Riemann surface using Riemann-Hurwitz formula:

$X=\{[x_0,x_1,x_2]\in\Bbb P^2\mid x_2^2x_0=\prod_{i=1}^3(x_1-\lambda_ix_0),\lambda_i\in\Bbb C\}, \lambda_i$ are distinct numbers.

---

An example:

For homogeneous polynomial $P(z_0,z_1,z_2)=z_0^n+z_1^n+z_2^n$, $P=0$ 
defines a compact Riemann surface.

$M=\{[z_0,z_1,z_2]\in\Bbb CP^2|P(z_0,z_1,z_2)=0\}$.

To compute its genus, comsider $f:M\to \Bbb CP^1, [z_0,z_1,z_2] \mapsto [z_0,z_1]$, it's a well-defined meromorphic function, $f^{-1}([0,1])=\{[0,1,z_2]|z_2^n=-1\}$.

$f$ is $n$-sheeted, has $n$ branch points, each point with ramification index $n-1$. Total ramification number is $n(n-1).$

From Riemann-Hurwitz formula, genus of $N$ is $\frac 12(n-1)(n-2)$

---

But for $X=\{[x_0,x_1,x_2]\in\Bbb P^2|x_2^2x_0=\prod_{i=1}^3(x_1-\lambda_ix_0),\lambda_i\in\Bbb C\}$,

how can we find such a $f: X\to \Bbb CP^1$ whose sheet number and branch points can be easily find out?

Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at $\phi\colon X\to\mathbb{P}^1; [x_0,x_1,x_2]\mapsto[x_0,x_1]$.  It has degree 2 and ramified only when $x_2^2x_0=0$, so this is ramified over 4 points $[x_0,x_1]=[1,\lambda_i]$ or "$[0,0]$", the limit $x_0,x_1\to 0$, and Riemann-Hurwitz gives $g=1$.

Comment: Thank you, and how did you find degree and ramification point of $\phi$? I tried to find preimage of $\phi$ but failed.

Comment: For $x_0\neq 0$ and generic $x_1$ the RHS is nonzero and so only two values of $x_2$ works, hence degree 2.  You don't have distinct square-roots only when $x_2=0$ or when $x_0=x_1=0$, so that gives the four points mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, and why do you choose function $[x_0,x_1,x_2] \to [x_0,x_1]$ rather than $[x_0,x_1,x_2] \to [x_1,x_2]$ or $[x_0,x_1,x_2] \to [x_1,x_2]$ or other functions? Is there a criterion or technique to choose such a function from given algebraic surface to $\Bbb P^1$?

Comment: You want the degree to be low, so ramification points and their indices are easy to analyse.  Note the $x_2^2$ is the only appearance of $x_2$ in the defining equation, so it makes sense to consider this map.